# How to remove the validation after you clear input fields

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

This is my script using ajax for my live validation in input field.

My problem is that I want something after you delete all your inputs the validation will remove.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").blur(function(){
            var email = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"../include/request.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:
                {
                    email_add:email
                },
                datatype: "text",
                success:function(html){
                    $('#availability').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="eadd">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
   placeholder="Enter email"required>
    <div id="availability" class="mt-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when there is no value in email field, it should not check validation?
If that is the case then just add condition to check if (email != ""). so on blur it will not call event again.

Comment: Go it bro thank you for you response!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the codes below.

What I added is to put a default display on the availability section as it is better to not leave it empty.

I also check if the email field is not empty for the validation to kick in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").blur(function(){
            $('#availability').html('(pending)');

            var email = $(this).val();

            if(email != ''){

              $.ajax({
                  url:"../include/request.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data:
                  {
                      email_add:email
                  },
                  datatype: "text",
                  success:function(html){
                      $('#availability').html(html);
                  }
              });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```